# piwik setCustomVariable not working

Tags: javascript, matomo

I use piwik to track my web page visits and it works fine.
I just added this code to the javascript on my page:

```
var _paq = _paq || [];
      _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      (function() {
        var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "mypiwiklink";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
        g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
       })();
      // end piwik track code
```

This code has no problem. It is standard.
Now I would like to add a custom variable, that tracks each call of specific function on my page.
So inside the code of the function, I've added:

```
   var selectTableRowHandler = function() {

        // function code

        //piwik code inside the function code:

                                 var _paq = _paq || [];
                                _paq.push(['setCustomVariable',  
                                    1, 
                                    "Visitor",
                                    "myfile", 
                                    "page" 
                                    ]);
                                  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
                                  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
                                  (function() {
                                    var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "mypiwiklink";
                                    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
                                    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
                                    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
                                    g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
                                  })();


// end of function code here

}
```

When I debug, I see that the code is executed without errors, but I can't see any custom varibales added at the piwik dashboard.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `var _paq = _paq || [];` outside of the function, I'm not sure but I think it's needed to be in the same scope as piwik.js

Comment: Been a while... Do you see a `_cvars` GET param in the request? I'd recommend using Firebug with the 'Net' feature. Look at the request, that gets sent from your machine to piwik. For a direkt response from Piwik, and what it sees, you can copy the location of your piwik request into a new tab, add `debug=1` somewhere in the GET params, and execute it. First, don't forget to add `[Tracker] \r debug_on_demand = 1` somewhere in your `path/to/piwik/public/config/config.ini.php` and you get the debug output.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a function you should use `window._paq` instead of `_paq`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume You have put / inserted the pageView tracking code in the < head > ..< /head > tag. The code may look like as follows (**changed _paq to window._paq as per latest matomo tracking code**) :

```
<script> var _paq = window._paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "mypiwiklink";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
    g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
   })(); // end piwik track code
  </script>
```

Up to this your code will work fine and will capture the data. But when you try to include this code in the function Matomo will stop tracking the visits on the site. To avoid this just modify your code as follows:

If you want to put this tracking code inside the function then define the _paq outside the function as follows:

```
<script> 
//define _paq outside the function. Its scope should not be limited up to this function only. It will be used to track individual events as well in the body tag.
var _paq = window._paq || [];  
var selectTableRowHandler = function() {

    // function code

    //piwik code inside the function code:


                            _paq.push(['setCustomVariable',  
                                1, 
                                "Visitor",
                                "myfile", 
                                "page" 
                                ]);
                              _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
                              _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
                              (function() {
                                var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "mypiwiklink";
                                _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
                                _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
                                var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
                                g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
                              })();// end of function code here}     
 </script>
```

Try the above solution it worked for me. let me know if you still face the problem.